# This.setState ignoring

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with one function of my project. I have this code

```
async handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        await this.setState({
            errors: {
                name: !this.state.values.name ? 'Enter name' : null,
                tel: !this.state.values.tel ? 'Enter phone number' : null
        }
        });
        if (!this.state.errors.name && !this.state.errors.tel) {
            this.props.createUser([this.state.values.name, this.state.values.tel]);
        }
    }
```

And this code ignore setState at first click on the button. How I can fix it?

Comment: Wondering why are you `await`ing your `this.setState` here? If you're waiting on state to be updated, maybe using the second argument to setState or a function state update would be a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour, is because `setState` is not working synchronously. `setState` actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. This is explained in the documentation of `setState`. You cannot use `await`since `setState` does not return a promise.

`setState` accepts a callback as second parameter, which runs immediately after the state change is performed.

```js
handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.setState({
        errors: {
            name: !this.state.values.name ? 'Enter name' : null,
            tel: !this.state.values.tel ? 'Enter phone number' : null
        }
    }, () => {
        if (!this.state.errors.name && !this.state.errors.tel) {
            this.props.createUser([this.state.values.name, this.state.values.tel]);
        });
    }
}
```